# Duplicate/Replicate tensorflow layers with same properties to form a graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

The task I try to implement by using a neural network differs a bit from its most common usage. I try to simulate a physical process by propagating something from the input to the output layer by optimizing the network's weights which represents physical properties.

Therefor I need a i.e. 150 layer network where each layer has the same properties in the form

> mx+b

where x is my variable I like to optimize and m an external factor which is the same for each layer (b is not in use right now).

I would like to automate the process of creating the graph rather than copy/paste each layer. So is there a function to copy the structure of the first layer to all following layers?

In tensorflow it should look like something like this here:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    # Input data.
    tf_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(n_data, n))
    tf_spatial_grid = tf.constant(m_index_mat)
    tf_ph_unit = tf.const(m_unit_mat)
    tf_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(n_data, n))

    # new hidden layer 1    
    hidden_weights = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([n*n, 1]) )
    hidden_layer = tf.nn.matmul( tf.matmul( tf_input, hidden_weights), tf_ph_unit)

    # new hidden layer 2
    hidden_weights_2 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([n*n, 1]) )
    hidden_layer_2 = tf.nn.matmul( tf.matmul( hidden_layer, hidden_weights_2), tf_ph_unit)
```

......

```
    # new hidden layer n
    hidden_weights_n = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([n*n, 1]) )
    hidden_layer_n = tf.nn.matmul( tf.matmul( hidden_layer_m, hidden_weights_n), tf_ph_unit)
```

...

So is there any option that automates this process somehow? Maybe I'm missing something

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: all you have to do is literally create a **for loop**. That's all, you do not need references to your hidden layers, just the previous one.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. How would I do this precisely? Do you have an example for that? I define the first hidden_layer and hidden_weights and in the for-loop I just the last hidden_layer as the input for my matmul()? How do I make sure, that the graph is build correctly? I guess I'm missing some knowledge sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish that is to create a function that builds your layer and simply invoke the function multiple times, possibly in a loop.

For instance:

```
def layer(input):
    hidden_weights = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([n*n, 1]) )
    hidden_layer = tf.nn.matmul( tf.matmul( input, hidden_weights), tf_ph_unit)
    return hidden_layer
```

and then:

```
input = tf_input
for i in range(10):
    input = layer(input)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response! I'm not yet familiar with python/tensorflow. Could you provide a quick pseudo-code/example how this might work? Or just give some keywords I should look for? I'm just slowly transiting from Matlab to Python - so I don't know any function which could do that ;)